# directories of Freetype are not creating saying C compiler is not available

Tags: gcc, compiler

```
FreeType build system -- automatic system detection

The following settings are used:

  platform                    unix
  compiler                    cc
  configuration directory     ./builds/unix
  configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk

If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
`config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.

Otherwise, simply type `make' again to build the library,
or `make refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).

cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure  '--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-m32CXXFLAGS=-m32LDFLAGS=-m32'
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/vr/vv/freetype-2.4.12/builds/unix':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
builds/unix/detect.mk:86: recipe for target 'setup' failed
make: *** [setup] Error 77
```

Comment: What is the exact command that you used? the run-on string `'CFLAGS=-m32CXXFLAGS=-m32LDFLAGS=-m32'` looks suspicious

Answer (score 0):

At first freetype [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=freetype).

If you need to compile it you should enable Source code repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) then install `build-essential` package and freetype's build-dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep freetype
```

You can check that it builds sucessfully with

```
apt-get source freetype --compile
```

If you are trying to compile packages for embedded system you can consult its build-system and toolchain documentation. If you are trying to compile 32bit libraries on 64bit system - it will be simpler if you use debootstrap of schroot.